# Passing a prop down 2 layers of children?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a component and I pass in an id as a prop:

```
<comments myId="1"></comments>
```

And on the comments component I have it as a prop:

```
props: [
    'myId',
],
```

Inside this comments component template I have another component

```
<btn id="{{ this.myId }}"></btn>
```

But i cannot seem to pass the prop down - I get the error:

```
Interpolation inside attributes has been removed. Use v-bind or the colon shorthand instead. For example, instead of <div id="{{ val }}">, use <div :id="val">.
```

I don't see why I need to use `:`, I'm happy to pass the id as a string.

How can I resolve the error, and pass down the prop?

Comment: This is breaking change in vuejs 2 and it is documented in the migration guide: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Interpolation-within-Attributes-removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can write down

```
<btn :id="myId"></btn>
```

to pass the props in to component.

syntax for passing props is this we can bind variable to component using bind we don't need to interpolate values there.

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  template: '#child', 
  props: ['id']
});

Vue.component('childchild', {
  template: '#childchild', 
  props: ['id']
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  },
  created: function() {
   
  },
  methods: {
     
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.3/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">  
  <child id="1000"></child>  
</div>

<template id="child">
  <childchild :id="id"></childchild>
</template>

<template id="childchild">
 <h1>{{ id }}</h1>
</template>
```